# I'm trying to use message template for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, json

I want to create template for push notification so far I'm stuck here and it's not working.

```
public static async void SendPushNotificationApns1(string msgTemplate)
{
    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(ListenConnectionString, NotificationHubName);
    string msg = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(msgTemplate)\"}}";

    await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(msg);
}
```

Comment: It happened with:
     string msg = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + $"{messageParam}" +"\"}}";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened with: `string msg = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + $"{messageParam}" +"\"}}";`